# Left Navigation Menu creation

Tags: liferay-6

I have lot of portlet pages which they are showing by click on left side menu bar..
I have found two solutions:

1. by using navigation.vm to do (but I don't know how to call my portlets into navigation bar links)
2. by using web content display portlet(but this also i don't know how to add my portlet )
   I try to create web content display portlet there I add source (HTML and CSS), but it won't take my CSS..

I call it like this:

```
<ul class="lnav">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>

here i added css

script="text/css"
  ul.lnav{list-style:none; background-color:#D8D8D8; color:#fff; font-size:10px; width:220px; }
</script>
```

and here I don't know how to call my portlet to that link, I'd appreciate any suggestion

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Hi Pankaj,i will explain my requirement with example:i want to display in a window like 30/70,in 30 part i want to display a navigation bar(left navigation bar contains four links),if i click on link in navigation bar,proper portlet will display in right side part(70 part),how i can do this by using Web content display or navigation.vm

Comment: Pankaj,if we are using panel pages is there any chance to change css?if yes means how i can achieve it?if not means tell me other way to change css

Answer (score 0):

One option for you is to use the panel pages of liferay. There you can specify what are the applications that should be available in the left navigation.

[image]

Using this will result into a page like this..[image]

Comment: Hi Danish,wr i can find panel in liferay 6.2

Comment: Goto add page --> in page type select Panel on place of Empty page

Comment: Thanks Danish,Able to do this,this what i want,and i have one more question,how add css to left side panel part?because i want to increase size of box

Comment: You can create a hook, and change the css there.

Comment: Danish i have one more doubt,panel part is default part in liferay..so how my changes added by using hook project?

Comment: is there any suggestions?